# What nutrients can support an immune system to counteract intense workouts?

Tags: nutrition, exercise

I have observed repeatedly that if I push myself in an aerobic workout, then not just my muscles, but my immune system also takes a beating. My chance of catching a cold is then much higher. I've made this correlation so frequently that I no longer have any doubt there is a connection.

One solution is presumably not to workout too hard, but can this be solved nutritionally? Is there a set of nutrients with which I can replenish my system just before or after an intense workout to counteract the resulting weaker immune system?